# Laravel pass data from seeder to factory

Tags: php, laravel

I's it possible to pass data from seeder to factory?

I'm building an app that needs to have added data on beginning

```
//seeder
public function run()
{
    $id = 0 //can i pass this var to factory?
    factory(App\VehicleCategory::class, 16)->create();
}

//factory
$factory->define(VehicleCategory::class, function (Faker $faker) {

$data = [
    'MICRO','SEDAN','CUV','SUV','MINIVAN','HATCHBACK','ROADSTER',
    'PICKUP','VAN','COUP'TRUCK','BIG TRUCK'
];

return [
    //
    'name' => $data[$id]
];
$id++;

});
```

I tried to bypass this put it doesn't work too

Tried to do it like this but it always return same id

```
$id = 0

$data = [
    'MICRO','SEDAN','CUV','SUV','MINIVAN','HATCHBACK','ROADSTER',
    'PICKUP','VAN','COUP'TRUCK','BIG TRUCK'
];


if(VehicleCategory::count() != 0){
    $id = VehicleCategory::latest()->first()->id;
}

return [
    //
    'name' => $data[$id]
];
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, have you considered putting `$id = 0` in the factory instead of the seeder? I don't see why it's useful in the seeder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to generate random data except for the name in the factory, just keep the factory by default and override the 'name'

So for example (using the default UserFactory Laravel ships with)

Then in the seeder

```php
public function run()
{
   $data = ['MICRO', 'SEDAN', 'CUV', 'SUV', 'MINIVAN', 'HATCHBACK', 'ROADSTER', 'PICKUP', 'VAN', 'COUP', 'TRUCK', 'BIG TRUCK'];

   foreach ($data as $name) {
      factory(User::class)->create(['name' => $name]);
   }
}
```

Results

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "MICRO",
        "email": "maximillia94@example.net",
        "email_verified_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36",
        "created_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "SEDAN",
        "email": "ziemann.bill@example.com",
        "email_verified_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36",
        "created_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "CUV",
        "email": "don90@example.org",
        "email_verified_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36",
        "created_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "SUV",
        "email": "dkoepp@example.net",
        "email_verified_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36",
        "created_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "MINIVAN",
        "email": "laney.schaden@example.com",
        "email_verified_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36",
        "created_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "HATCHBACK",
        "email": "herman.addison@example.net",
        "email_verified_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36",
        "created_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "ROADSTER",
        "email": "thaddeus89@example.org",
        "email_verified_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36",
        "created_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36"
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "PICKUP",
        "email": "eusebio32@example.net",
        "email_verified_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36",
        "created_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "VAN",
        "email": "caleb77@example.net",
        "email_verified_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36",
        "created_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36"
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "COUP",
        "email": "foster.kiehn@example.com",
        "email_verified_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36",
        "created_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36"
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "TRUCK",
        "email": "ophelia62@example.net",
        "email_verified_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36",
        "created_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36"
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "BIG TRUCK",
        "email": "elsie41@example.com",
        "email_verified_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36",
        "created_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-29 17:49:36"
    }
]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I wanted

Comment: Glad it helped, please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem